# Hibernate classes are not loaded even i have maven dependecies in pom.xml

Tags: hibernate, maven

I am able to see all jars in my local repository, but when I try to write Hibernate `Util` class which contains `Session`, `SessionFactory` classes, it shows compile time errors, even I can't see any import for that classes, please help me out in this.

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

in this statement `SessionFactory` and `Configuration` classes are not resolved.

Comment: Show us some code and the errors that you get.

Answer (score 0):

Your local repository is the place where libraries are stored. Having a jar file there doesn't automatically mean that it's on your classpath. Your Maven pom.xml needs to have the respective dependencies explicitly defined so that they can be used. Once you do that, you'll most-likely need to re-run `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, `mvn idea:idea`, or... whatever the goal is for your IDE.